# Are there any serious plans for a new supersonic civilian aircraft?

Tags: supersonic, aircraft-manufacturer

Since the retirement of the Concorde and the Tupolev Tu-144, there aren't any civilian airplanes (passengers carrier or business jet) flying supersonic. I heard that Dassault and SAAB had rather advanced studies on this topic but abandoned them due to various problems.

Does anyone have current references indicating that an aircraft manufacturer plans to develop a supersonic transport aircraft?

Comment: I think this will be a difficult question to answer. First, it's highly speculative and unless you work for a manufacturer it's unlikely you can say anything for sure (and even then your employer might limit what you can say publicy). Second, it's also subjective because one man's "serious plan" is another's "daydream". It might make for a great discussion, but it can't be answered 'correctly' in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that it is probably OT, but it is a question that we're likely to see often.  I wonder how best to restructure these questions

Comment: I don't think this is primarily opinion based (serious may be subject to opinion, but I think most people would agree on what is not serious), and while I question whether it's answerable, I think it's a legitimate question to ask, and I don't see the harm. Maybe the answer right now is "No", and maybe down the road someone will identify a "Yes".

Comment: I'm not sure about "primarily opinion based" but this question is asking for information that seems "way to rapidly changing" -- Even if we use well-sourced information to formulate an answer, if we're not going to then keep the list of "serious plans" up to date our answer will be obsolete in a few months/years. Which ones got built? Which died on the drawing board? What new designs popped up? etc...

Comment: Here's another one: [BBC: Spike Aerospace S-512 supersonic jet - expected 2018](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-26258971)

Answer (score 6):

[Aerion](http://aerioncorp.com/) is planning a supersonic business jet which has a projected completion year of 2021:

[image]

Here's an article [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/grantmartin/2013/10/31/the-worlds-first-supersonic-business-jet-will-fly-in-2021/) have written about it.